# SQL value changes

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i have a table t1:

| Product id | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 |
| 1 | p2 |
| 2 | p1 |
| 2 | p1 |
| 2 | p1 |

What i want to know is, for a unique product id i want to see if there has been a new price.

Only having constant values for a specific product id is of not interest.

Would appreciate some tips.

Best regards

My thoughts is something like "Select the product ids' where its distinct(count(price)) > 1. This should give me only the products ids that has a price change?

If a product id only has the same price without a change, it's of no interest to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to check `COUNT(DISTINCT price > 1)` is correct.

We just need to use `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT price) > 1
ORDER BY product_id;
```

If also the different prices should be shown, this query can be used as subquery. For example:

```
SELECT product_id, price
FROM t1
WHERE product_id IN 
(SELECT product_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT price) > 1)
ORDER BY product_id;
```

Or we could use `JOIN` rather than `IN` which could have a better performance:

```
SELECT t1.product_id, t1.price
FROM t1
JOIN  
(SELECT product_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT price) > 1) sub
ON t1.product_id = sub.product_id
ORDER BY t1.product_id;
```

We can try out these queries here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7KRnSeB3)

Comment: Thank you, this gives an output with only unique product ids though because the group by?

What if i would like to have the whole "set" of product id's(not unique) and prices that fulfill the requirement.

Could i do that in a sub query like:

SELECT product_id
FROM t1

WHERE product id IN
(SELECT product_id from t1 GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT price) < 1)

ORDER BY product_id ;

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT product_id
FROM   t1
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY product_id
  ORDER BY price
  PATTERN (^ first_price+ second_price)
  DEFINE
    first_price AS price  =  FIRST(price),
    second_price AS price != FIRST(price)
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 ( Product_id, Price ) AS
SELECT 1, 'p1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'p2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'p1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'p1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'p1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PRODUCT_ID |
| --- |
| 1 |

---

If you want the two prices then:

```sql
SELECT product_id, price1, price2
FROM   t1
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY product_id
  ORDER BY price
  MEASURES
    FIRST(price) AS price1,
    LAST(price)  AS price2
  PATTERN (^ first_price+ second_price)
  DEFINE
    first_price AS price  =  FIRST(price),
    second_price AS price != FIRST(price)
);
```

Which outputs:

| PRODUCT_ID | PRICE1 | PRICE2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | p2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u1JfNcy4)